# How to associate pressing "enter" with clicking button?

Tags: java, swing, listener, keypress

In my swing program I have a JTextField and a JButton. I would like for, once the user presses the "enter" key, the actionListener of the JButton runs. How would I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: getRootPane().setDefaultButton(JButton defaultButton);

Answer (score 10):

JRootPane has a method setDefaultButton(JButton button) that will do what you want.  If your app is a JFrame, it implements the RootPaneContainer interface, and you can get the root pane by calling getRootPane() on the JFrame, and then call setDefaultButton on the root pane that was returned.  The same technique works for JApplet, JDialog or any other class that implements RootPaneContainer.

Comment: Does this only work after you have initialized the component with which you plan to .getRootPane() on? If so, that would mean I could not build this directly into that component's constructor, yes?

Comment: @LucasMorgan: you need a JRootPane for this to work, and that makes sense. Else you may need to use key bindings.

Answer (score 3):

there is an example here

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/SwingDefaultButton.htm

this is what you need:  rootPane.setDefaultButton(button2);

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of ActionListeners.  That's the old style for doing listeners.  Graduate to the Action class.  The trick is to understand InputMaps and ActionMaps work.  This is a unique feature of Swing that is really quite nice:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Here's how you do it:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout( new TableLayout( ... ) );
Action someAction = new AbstractAction( "GO" )  {
    public void actionPerformed() {
    }
};

InputMap input = panel.getInputMap( JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT );

input.put( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( "enter", "submit" );
panel.getActionMap().put("submit", someAction );

panel.add( button = new JButton( someAction ) );
panel.add( textField = new JTextField( ) );
```

Using the WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT allows the panel to receive keyboard events from any of it's child (i.e. ancestors).  So no matter what component has focus as long as it's inside the panel that keystroke will invoke any action registered under "submit" in the ActionMap.

This allows you to reuse Actions in menus, buttons, or keystrokes by sharing them.

Comment: Key Binding is useful in many situations but isn't a bit of overkill for the current problem when you could use the other simpler solutions offered (that likely use key binding in the background though).

Comment: Depends the author didn't specify if this was on a dialog by itself, or the main UI.  Using setDefaultButton() assumes it's the only thing on a dialog.  Not to mention understanding Actions and how they relate to the rest of the Swing toolkit takes you further into other topics like menu bindings, global keystrokes, and customizes key mappings for default components.  Plus, anyone using ActionListeners needs to be aware Actions are superior in all cases.

Comment: "anyone using ActionListeners needs to be aware Actions are superior in all cases." -- Hm, and I was taught that all generalizations are wrong. :)

Comment: Once you go Actions you never go ActionListener.  :-)  Seriously ActionListeners are superseded by Actions in terms of integration, ease of use, and centralizing features that are harder to manage using ActionListener.

Comment: @chubbard: "For this reason, you should take care to only use `Action`s where their benefits are desired, and use simple ActionListeners elsewhere."— http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html

Comment: That's at best a probably minor optimization.  If that really bothers you can overcome that by being lazy and not allocating event listener storage until you your first listener is registered.  Action is an interface so you can always implement your own that could optimize that away.  I've used Action's extensively for years and not once had memory issues with it. And, that's through plenty of profiling and reducing memory footprints.  Not once has my use of Actions ever come up on the radar as consuming massive amounts of memory.  My last fairly sizable UI only consumed 10MB after startup.

Comment: @chubbard: It's a trade-off, but you're right that `Action` should be considered sooner rather than later.

Comment: I've got exactly the same situation as the OP - a JTextField alongside a JButton. As suggested above, by placing these in a `JPanel`, writing an `Action` and associating this with the `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` `InputMap`, I can get my action invoked when I press the enter button on either widget without duplicating code.